# How can I transform a query into a dense vector before it is actually used by Solr?

Tags: solr, semantic-search

I am trying to transform the normal query inserted by the user, into a dense vector in order to use the semnatic search now available in the last version of Apache Solr. I would like to do the "text to vector" conversion Solr side.

I found some information on Search Handlers and Query pre-processing but I am still confused if it is possible to do and I found no clear example on how to do something like this.
For now I made a web service that I can use for the conversion but I need the hook mechanism to use it in Solr.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.